# Paged Pool memory leak in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, memory

Paged Pool is constantly rising.
After 24 hours, I have a paged pool of 800MB.

The tags with highest paged pool usage as of now are:
1>MmSt 146396864 K
2>CM31 126894080 K
3>XNS   49524736 K

How do I reduce paged pool usage? Is it normal for Windows 8.1 x64 to have an 800MB+ paged pool after 1 day of casual use consisting of web browsing and watching movies and nothing else?
Please help.

If you need more information, please ask.
Total installed RAM is 8GB.

Screenshot of PoolMon:
[image]

Update: 
I have an uptime of about 12 hours, and my paged pool is at 873 MB.
[image: Paged Pool]
Poolmon looks like this:
[image: poolmon]

Please suggest. It's **ALWAYS** MmSt that's increasing wildly, not CM31 or anything else.. Had Intel Rapid Storage driver installed, I uninstalled it and m now using the default Windows 8.1 storage driver but the issue has not been resolved :(

Comment: CM31 = registry and MmSt = Memory management. How long does t takes until you see a grow? You have to sue xperf/WPA to trace this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool Increase the MaxFile value to 2048 if it takes a bit longer to see a grow.

Comment: Magicandre1981, they grow as i use the computer- watch videos, browse web in firefox, play mp3s, write in ms word, pretty much anything i do will cause a steady growth of paged pool. If i leave the computer turned on but idle, it doesn't grow much- but if i use it, it'll hit 800MB in a day, 1.5GB in 2 days.... Only paged pool, non-paged pool generally stays below 150 MB... :(

Comment: the MSDN link you gave is not opening here, it says "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."...

Comment: This has been manually transferred from [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43080/800mb-paged-pool-size-in-windows-8-1) and the OP went into more detail there.

Comment: try this link: http://pastebin.com/fvugmGtP

Comment: @MarkHurd: So he did. Wonder why he didn't just copy-paste the entire question as-is?

Comment: downloading xperf from your new link now.. will post results..

Comment: @karan, i tried, but it wasn't letting me paste images here. The first image i posted was actually a link to an external image hosting site, i think a helpful moderator has allowed me image posting privileges now ...:)

Comment: Strange. I thought new user restrictions only went away at 10 rep, so wonder how you can post images now?

Comment: @karan, It's good that I can now.. It'd be very difficult for others to check my poolmon if i couldn't. Any idea what could be causing this huge paged pool usage? I've run sfc/scannow, it says problems could not be fixed. m now running a DISM, I didn't install anything new, other than Windows updates and Avira free updates, can't think of anything that could have damaged my Windows. I did a CHKDSK/F too, no problems found...

Comment: Run DISM and then SFC and let us know.

Comment: share the xperf trace, otherwise you'll never get a solution.

Comment: have you uploaded the trace?

Comment: I've voted now to close the topic as too broad because without the ETL we can't help you.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but I just experienced a multi-gigabyte leak by transferring thousands of files from my Android phone over USB. I traced the allocation back to the MmSt paged pool tag.